# Shutdown multicasted Observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I created an Observable which was `publish`ed, and subscribed to by many Observers.

I want to shut it down arbitrarily. I know that if I do `refCount`, it will be shut down automatically, when all Observers will unsubscribe, but I'd like to shut down manually, without storing and going over all Disposables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `dispose` on the `Disposable` returned by [`connect`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#connect--) but note that this may leave observers in an active state as they won't receive any further events. You have to dispose those as well anyway.

```java
ConnectableObservable co = source.publish();
Disposable d = co.connect();

Disposable d1 = co.subscribe();
Disposable d2 = co.subscribe();

d.dispose();

d1.dispose();
d2.dispose();
```

If you want to avoid the hanging part, use `takeUntil` with a subject:

```
PublishSubject terminate = PublishSubject.create();

ConnectableObservable co = source.publish();
Disposable d = co.connect();

terminate.doOnComplete(d::dispose).subscribe();

Observable observable = co.takeUntil(terminate);

observable .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace,
    () -> System.out.println("Done 1"));
observable .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace,
    () -> System.out.println("Done 2"));

terminate.onComplete();
```

Comment: I am very confused by the second example. onComplete will both trigger `d`'s dispose method, and takeUntil's boundary? Doesn't that shut the source observer twice? Or does takeUntil take care of the Observers?

Comment: No. The takeUntil disposes the subscriptions to the connectable source but would not disconnect on its own. I.e., if only you had d1.dispose and d2.dispose from the first example. The connectable must be explicitly disconnected. For more clarity, you could use source.takeUntil.publish so that the termination happens above the shared sequence.